# Tensorflow GPU Device "Failed to get device properties"

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

When I run `session.run()` with my deep learning model in Python Tensorflow, for some reason, I get the following error:

```
E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:87] Failed to get device properties, error code: 30

Failed to initialize GPU device #0: unknown error

\tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_2d_gpu.h:441] Non‑OK‑status: 

CudaLaunchKernel(ShuffleInTensor3Simple, config.block_count, config.thread_per_block, 0, d.stream(), config.virtual_thread_count, in.data(), combined_dims, out.data()) status: Internal: invalid configuration argument
```

I'm using a Windows laptop with both an integrated Intel graphic card as well as an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 GPU. I'm also using tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0.

Sometimes, if this error doesn't pop up, the kernel in my Spyder IDE restarts and then just stops working. If not, the results that I get from the `session.run()` are completely wrong.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

I actually was able to resolve it by updating my NVIDIA GPU graphics driver. Now it's working!